# Spark's call function

Tags: java, apache-spark

Sorry, basic question about Spark. Can I use Java object different than primitive type inside a Spark's call function? For instance, imagine that I have something like that:

```
JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile(dataFile);
    JavaRDD<String> output;
    output = input.map(new Function<String, String>() { public String call(String s) throws MalformedURLException {
            SystemConfiguration config = new SystemConfiguration();
```

....

If I remove the instance of my own class SystemConfiguratin it works fine, but with it inside it doesn't work (Spark finished with failure).
Please could you shed light about this? Many thanks

Comment: See: How to create a [mcve]?

Comment: Possible there is something went wrong inside your SystemConfiguration class

Answer (score 0):

As long as the objects you create inside your transformations are either Serializable or declared @transient lazy ( for non serializable ones) you are good.

Comment: So, if my object is not serializable or not declared @transient lazy I have nothing to do...

Comment: if it is not serializable then you have to declare it as @transient lazy. If it is serializable then you don't need to decorate your object instantiations in any way and use it as you normally do.